# Error: attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

I get the following error in my Lua code:

> attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)

It happens on the line below in bold. How can I fix it?

```
function SendMessageToAdmins(color1, color2, color3, msg)
    for i = 0, maxSlots - 1 do
        if Account[i] and Account[i].Admin >= 1 or Account[i] and Account[i].GameMaster >= 1 then
            SendPlayerMessage(i, color1, color2, color3, string.format("%s", msg))
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: It's hard to know why this error is happening without knowing where `Account` comes from and what it is expected to contain.

Comment: A (meta)table, probably. It seems like a global variable here. Maybe you specified it as local incorrectly?

Comment: please read [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Not OP related, but lua arrays are 1-based indexed.

Answer (score 9):

this error usually comes from trying to index a field on something that isn't a table, or nil. chances are that whatever is at `Account[i]` when the error happens, isn't a table or userdata, but a built in type like a string or number.

i'd start with checking the type of whatever is in `Account[i]` when you get that error, and going from there.

the two most common ways to see this error (that i know of) are below:

```
local t = { [1] = {a = 1, b = 2}, [2] = {c = 3, d = 4} }
-- t[5] is nil, so this ends up looking like nil.a which is invalid
-- this doesn't look like your case, since you check for 
-- truthiness in Account[i]
print(t[5].a)
```

the case you are probably experiencing, is most likely this one:

```
local t =
{
    [1] = {a = 1, b = 2},
    [2] = 15, -- oops! this shouldn't be here!
    [3] = {a = 3, b = 4},
}
-- here you expect all the tables in t to be in a consistent format.
-- trying to reference field a on an int doesn't make sense.
print(t[2].a)
```

Comment: The message in your code is "attempt to index field '?' (a number value)" but the OP reports *nil* instead of *number*.

Comment: good catch, i didn't even notice that... either way - it's hard to tell what exactly is wrong w/out a working example.

Comment: I notice this error at times when I’ve copied code over from somewhere, and for some reason the spaces at the start of end of lines seem to become the issue.  If I go through and ensure that any spaces (unless absolutely required) are removed it removes this error. (Not exactly sure of the cause maybe text formatting or something, but it’s a very hard to see unless you can tell spaces etc are present.