# imitate C struct in Lua

Tags: lua

I'm trying to imitate the structs of C in Lua.

I'm trying to do this, but it's not working

```lua
struct = {}
struct[1].type = "some type"
```

Appears this

`attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)`

And I want to do it too

```lua
struct = {}
struct[1].something[1].var[1] = "some type"
```

Can someone help me with it?

Sorry if I'm doing something very wrong.

Comment: `struct` doesn't have an element with index `1`.  You have to create one first.  `struct = {}; struct[1] = {}; struct[1].type = "some type"`

Comment: @HenriMenke, please post your comment as an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153537/error-attempt-to-index-field-a-nil-value)

Comment: @lhf I think it's a duplicate, see comment above.

Comment: @HenriMenke thanks, works well now. I can't see the answer in the link above. The solution for the second problem I did ```struct[i][h] = {}; struct[i][h][z] = "something"```